# hash function notations and existing cryptographic hash algorithms

Tags: hash, access-control, sha-256

I am implementing Role-based access control by referencing the paper [Enforcing Role-Based Access Control for Secure Data Storage in the Cloud](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2011/09/02/comjnl.bxr080.short). In page 6, they have mentioned to choose hash functions $H_1$ and $H_2$ during the setup

$$H1 : \{0, 1\}^∗ \rightarrow Z^∗_p,$$
$$H2 : G_T \rightarrow Z^∗_p$$
where $G_T$ be a cyclic multiplicative group.

Can anyone please explain me the notation of the two hash functions?
Should the two hash functions $H_1$ and $H_2$ be implemented using different cryptographic hash algorithms? or can I use $\operatorname{SHA-256}$ (for example) to implement both of them? If No, please recommend me cryptographic hash algorithms for them.

Comment: Voted to migrate to cryptoSE